# ng-repeat and jquery ui sortable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-ui-sortable

I've an ng-repeat in my angular template which needs to be sortable. I'm using jQuery-ui's Sortable to implement it.

The JS:

```
$scope.data = [{"key":123,"val":"a"},
{"key":124,"val":"b"},
{"key":125,"val":"c"}];

$(".sortable").sortable();
```

The template:

```
<div class="sortable"> 
    <div ng-repeat="sub in data" >
        {{sub.key}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine, and I can drag and drop the elements.
However, when a ng-repeat is nested within another, it doesn't work; I'm unable to drag anything. On using Chrome inspector, I see that the class 'ui-sortable' is not added to any element at all.

The JS:

```
$scope.subJson = [{"name":"MS1","slides":[{"title":"Title1"},{"title":"Title2"}]},{"name":"MS2","slides":[{"title":"Title3"},{"title":"Title4"}]}];

$(".sortable").sortable();
```

The template:

```
<div> 
    <div ng-repeat="sub in subJson" >
        {{sub.name}}
        <div class="sortable">
            <div ng-repeat="slide in sub.slides" >
                {{slide.title}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why does this happen? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this problem lies in the execution time of `$('.sortable').sortable()`.
Sortable finds elements with classname `sortable` immediately after the controller is set up.

At that time the `ng-repeat` has not been initiated, so the `$('.sortable')` finds no element.
In the js fiddle below, the output in console shows this problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5FWt/439/

A quick dirty fix is put `$('.sortable').sortable()` in a `setTimeout`.
However, manipulating dom element is never an angular way!
A desirable way to achieve this is to construct a directive, or use a angular-ui plugin like this, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Comment: Never thought of it in that way. thanks! doesn't setTimeout need a time in milliseconds value though?

Comment: The company I work for doesn't allow angular-ui yet. I use this controller for a directive in my code. Do you mean to say the sortable itself is to be handled as a separate directive?

Comment: If you're using controller for directive then manipulating dom is fine :) (At least for me). Putting sortable in this directive's `link` will be also fine, I think

Answer (score 1):

`Sortable` needs to reload the object to control.

Put the `$(".sortable").sortable()`; inside a function and then call that function in the item row of the list.

For example:

```
function init() {
    $(".sortable").sortable();
}
```

then in your html:

```
<div> 
<div ng-repeat="sub in subJson" >
    {{sub.name}}
    <div class="sortable">
        <div ng-repeat="slide in sub.slides" >
            <div class="layer-draggable" 
              ng-mousedown="init()">
                {{slide.title}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```